# Android storing user ID after login

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I was wondering what the best way is to store an user ID after logging the user in? I have just started Android Development, and have read about the Shared Preferences, but this does not seem to work?

This is happening in my `LoginActivity`:

```
        User user = dbHelper.findUser(email);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("user_id", user.getId());
        editor.commit();

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
```

In my `MainActivity` I would like to obtain the logged in user's ID as follows:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        String user_id = prefs.getString("user_id", "0");
```

Now, I need this user id in order to build lists based on the user, so I do database queries with this ID. What's the best way to do pass on this ID? I could just pass it on with intents, but storing it somewhere central is preferable. I do need this ID in multiple activities.

Comment: Please explain in detail what "does not seem to work?" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Because it will never obtain the correct ID. It seems like it always just gets the default value, which is "0" in this case.

Comment: Other than doing a lot of I/O on the main application thread, and not using a common definition for the `"user_id"` string (so you do not accidentally introduce a typo somewhere), what you have seems OK. Are you sure that `user.getId()` is returning what you think it is?

Comment: @CommonsWare Damn, you are right. It was the right way, but I was using some overloaded functions and used the wrong params. Got a null value all along. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Like user CommonsWare pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002248/android-storing-user-id-after-login?noredirect=1#comment80951148_47002248), the value did not return the one I intended, therefore always choosing the default value from my SharedPreferences.